# WPF WCF Entity Framework Can not view Classes in WPF project

Tags: wpf, wcf, entity-framework, service-reference

I am wprking on a project and I have 2 projects in one solution. I added my WCF project and inside it I added an entity framework. Also in Service1.svc I can reach the classes and use them for saving like

```
public  bool saveuser(User user)
{
}
```

For example User is the name of my database and Its pretty fine working in WCF part but at WPF part Im trying to access this class again to fill this class's object and I `using MyClass.ServiceReference1;` on the top and Inside one of my method I can not reach this class. What should be the solution why I can not access my class instead I added this WCF service as a service reference and enabled async operations.

Im newbie and thanks

Sincerely

Comment: can you expose a little of code for better understanding?

Comment: The class names are not coming. For example I have a User Database and can use User like User us = new User(); us.name = "aa"; in WCF its ok but WPF part even if I use service like using Myclass.ServiceReference1; I can not use such thing like User us = new User(); For example inside the constructor? I know I did it before but now I cant what might be the problem?

Comment: First of all, it's not advisable to pass the entities straight forward from a WCF service. You should use POCO classes. In WPF you cannot do User u = new User() but you should be able to do ServiceReference1.User or something like that...

Comment: I can not do ServiceReference1.User either that User is not the one I want I have category also and I can not view that category

Comment: without more information I really can't help you.